# CSS applied to one table does not work on another

Tags: html, css

While working on some dynamic styling for tables I ran across an issue that took me down a rabbit hole trying to apply a class and is driving me crazy.  I believe I found the root of my problem with this, but do not understand why it is happening.  I have a working CSS class applied to a table and displaying as expected - lets call the class "foo".  I noticed that I could not get any CSS to work on another table - lets call that CSS class "bar".  Here is the HTML for it:

```css
.foo th,
.bar th {
    background-color: #007FA4;
}

.foo tr:nth-child(even),
.bar tr:nth-child(even) {
    background-color: #D5D8DC;
}

.foo tr:hover,
.bar tr:hover {
    background-color: #3498DB;
}

.foo th,
.bar th {
    background-color: #87BED4;
}
```

```html
<table class="foo">
   <tr>
      <th>Foo Header</th>
   </tr>
   <tr class="sub-header">
      <th>Col</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Test 2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
<table class="bar">
   <tr>
      <th>Bar Header</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <th>Col</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Test 1</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Test 2</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

When I apply this, my "bar" table does not have any formatted applied to it.  However, if I change the "bar" table's class to be "foo" (no change to the CSS) it works and both tables are formatted.

This leads me to believe I am missing/do not understand something that is going on behind the scenes of CSS.  What would cause this type of behavior?

Comment: I've turned your code into a runnable snippet. As you can probably tell by running the snippet, the code you've included does not behave as described. Perhaps in your actual environment, you've typo'd something or have styles overriding what you expect. Easiest way to debug is always *Right Click > Inspect Element*, and see which styles are being applied. If a style is crossed out, it's being overridden. If it doesn't appear *at all*, then your selector is not correct.

Comment: No repro. Looks the same to me https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/zhe1tgy8/

Comment: Also not seeing what the OP has described.

Comment: What environmental factor might cause the issues described?  I understand it should work, but it simply is not for me, which is what is driving me crazy.

Comment: style sheet caching? press ctrl f5 in browser (windows)

Comment: @Clint, I think you got it. I opened it in a new browser and it showed up as expected.  However, just refreshing does not work.  The cache has to be cleared too.  Thanks, just needed a new set of eyes!

Comment: @notsodev You can avoid the need to reset cache by appending a version number to your stylesheets., e.g. `<link rel="myStyleSheet.css?v1">`. (Any changes after the `?` will cause a re-fetch, version number just seems the most obvious convention). This is also how you can be sure that visitors are seeing the latest styles without requiring them to clear their cache.